# Example for kernel timer Implementation in Linux

Tags: linux, kernel

Could you please give any basic example of a kernel timer (start_ktimer) implementation in Linux?

Comment: The answer is already answered here:- =P 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4039602/example-for-kernel-timer-implementation-in-linux-in-kernel-2-6-32

Answer (score 3):

What about this text on [LWN](http://lwn.net/Articles/152436/)? It describes the responsible struct which should get you started.